# Webpage messes up and fixes when refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Im working on a website, and I've currently ran into a problem thats got me mind boggled.

It happens on more than one page, but when I refresh the page, the navbar, search bar, and other things mess up all over the place.

When I click on a new link or refresh (sometimes) its back to normal. Then I refresh again the page looks messed up again.

my page is www.ram-bay.com if you want to have a look.
Sometimes when you refresh its okay. refresh a few times on any page it seems to mess up.

Can anyone seem to spot the problem?
Also before you ask me to link code... there is a lot of it

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: have you tested on multiple machines/browsers? No problems for me (Chrome 51 / OSX)

Comment: update: Did a right-click in chrome and got these beauties

GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
index.php:36 GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
index.php:29 GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is looking just fine in Chrome/Safari. What browser are you using?

I see that you're using bootstrap and jQuery over CDN, so maybe you have issues with your network connection. Try to get all file stored on your server and see if it fix the problem.

Comment: My files are all on the server as well as locally. I am connected to bootstrap and jquery via CDN.
Apparently on refresh, the CDN resets the connection and it messes up. Could it just be happening on my computer? because it wasnt happening before, it was fine earlier

Comment: It may be possible, I've seen behaviour lake that before, but at the end we reinstalled user machine and everything worked fine.

Comment: I think I solved the problem: Changed from CDN and downloaded the css and JS bootstrap files then uploaded them and re-linked.

Must have been a network error on my end. 
Moral of the story: Don't use CDN's.